# Moka pot question... brewing steps

Tags: moka

I needed to find a place where I could ask this question and get a knowledgable range of replies. Since stackexchange has been so useful in the past and I just discovered this Coffee Stackexchange, I'm asking here. I'm  more looking to see whether the responses here are equivalent to those found by searching online although in the case of this question, the range of answers is enough to drive you bonkers.

I have a 12-cup bialetti. We have always drunk Moka pot coffee in our home as essentially a way to make a caffe lungo, not for making espresso. It gives my wife and I two cups each brew. I think we've always been doing this right but because one can always learn, **what do people here think is the method for brewing coffee in a Moka pot?** Water temperature, grind size, time of the brew, etc etc. One thing for example is that we don't fill the filter basket. It just gives us the strength we like that way, but is it harming our coffee extraction to do that?

Thank you for your thoughts!

Comment: Welcome! Those are all interesting questions. Unfortunately, we (and all Stack Exchange sites) have a "one question per question" rule. Please take a moment to take the [tour] and browse through the [help], especially [ask], then [edit] your post so that it contains _one_ specific question. We can then reopen this post quickly. It's perfectly acceptable to post _multiple_ questions related to one topic, you can link them together if you think it may be helpful. Hint: for multiple good questions, the community can upvote you multiple times and you might gain reputation faster...

Comment: My apologies, Stephie. It's been a long time since I posted something on stackexchange. I will rephrase and go over the rules. Thanks for being kind about the reminder. Hell of a lot more productive than the way other sites correct you.

Comment: proper espresso is completely different from the coffee you can make with a moka because of water pressure and temperature

Comment: @El_Muntagnin I know that. That's why I said we don't use it for espresso.

Answer (score 0):

**Water temperature:**
I like to boil some water in a tea pot or something then add the water to the Moka pot. Starting with cold water takes time to heat it up, and this heating process will cause your coffee to have more bitter and acidic tastes

**grind size:**
Kinda depends on what you want. If you use finer grinds, the coffee taste stronger. However, as you pointed out, Moka pot can't be used to make espresso. So if you use fine grinds for an espresso machine, the coffee will turn out to be unpleasantly strong! A grind size between espresso and french press is good. Sorry if this is not helpful...... If you live in the US, the default grind you can find in any grocery store is perfect.

**time of the brew:**
Related to water temp. Start with boiled water, brew until coffee stops going. Of course no need to open the lid and watch - it's time when you see steam coming out the top of the pot. Once you see that, remove it from the stove right away.

Oh, and I always fill the basket. If you feel it's too strong that way, thy rougher grinds. If you don't fill it, I can imagine the coffee will be moving around when hot steam goes through, and that affects extraction. Filling the basket full makes sure they stay as a nice layer all the way through.

Enjoy your coffee!